# How to run/execute methods sequentially by Selenium RC and TestNG using Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-rc, sequential

I have a java class containing 3 methods:

```
public class Test{
 public void orange(){
 }
 public void apple(){
 }
 public void mango(){
 }
}
```

I want to execute 3 methods mentioned above sequentially/orderly as i have written by Selenium RC and TestNG. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way is to just change `@Test` to `@Test(singleThreaded=true)`.  If you do, all of the tests in your class will run sequentially in a single thread.

Or

If you want to be explicit about the order that the tests should run in, you can use the annotation @dependsOnMethods

```
public void orange(){}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "orange" })
public void apple(){}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "apple" })
public void mango(){}
```

This is also nice if you want some, but not all, of the methods in a class to run sequentially.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

Comment: Dependencies are the way to go. Also note that the more recent versions of TestNG support an XML attribute called "preserve-order" which will guarantee that your classes and methods are executed in the same order as found in your testng.xml file.

Comment: Yes, "preserve-order" of TestNG is worked well. I also used "@dependsOnMethods"

Answer (score 3):

Just change the `@Test` to `@Test(singleThreaded=true)` and you're good to go.

http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#singleThreaded%28%29

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you try this annotation at class level itself.

```
@Test(sequential = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using dependsOnGroups. Hence you club your test method as one group and provide dependency over this group. So tomorrow if you refactor your method name, your dependency structure would not be broken. For more on dependsOnGroups look [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `sequential=true` on the class, you can also set a priority on the methods themselves.

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void orange(){}

@Test(priority=2)
public void apple(){}

@Test(priority=3)
public void mango(){}
```